# How indicate in your curl request the route that you need to use in Azure IoT hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am reading multiple documentation about Routing for Azure IoT hub:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid-routing-comparison.md
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax.md
- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/tutorial-routing.md

But when you add in the section about "Routing query": level="storage" and you create the route, how to indicate in your curl request the route that you need to use.

Currently, the request that I use with curl is:

```
  curl --request POST \
    --url "https://${IOT_HUB}.azure-devices.net/devices/${DEVICE}/messages/events?api-version=2018-06-30" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" \
    --header "Authorization: ${SAS_TOKEN}" \
    --data "{ \"field1\" : \"value\", \"field2\" : \"value\" }" \
    --verbose
```

How to add the information about the route level="storage"?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The routing examples in the Microsoft documentation all show examples using the SDK, you need to add an item to the appProperties section of the message. But if you need to use the HTTP endpoint, you can add appProperties by including a header prefixed with "iothub-app-". So the header you would need to add in your curl command is

```
--header "iothub-app-level: storage" \
```

Find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/senddeviceevent)

Edit: I see Roman beat me by half a minute.

Comment: in the azure portal, in the examples appear this case: level="storage" but is it possible to put: `route:route1` and later in curl request use: `--header "iothub-app-route: route1" ` or the variable level is always fixed?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You can name it anything you want and use it in the IoT Hub route query. You can also apply boolean logic to combine multiple properties or even the message body. Some good examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax#message-routing-query-based-on-message-properties

Comment: I am going to test now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following header:

```
--header "iothub-app-level: storage" \
```